# python code - rate calculation. How can i make this code proper?

Tags: python

I have learned python by myself for 2 weeks! And I learned about 'self' things so I wanted to make rate calculation code using 'self'. But I constantly faced errors. The last error was "ratecalc object has no attribute 'ratemoney'". I understand what the error said literally, but I have no idea to solve this. How can I make this proper? Is there any hints?

```
class ratecalc(object):
    def __init__(self, initmoney, day, rate):
        self.initmoney=initmoney
        self.day=day
        self.rate=rate
    def calc(self):
        self.ratemoney=self.initmoney+self.initmoney*rate*day
        return self.ratemoney
    def __str__(self):
        return('%.2f $ in %i days, rate was %i ,total is %s'%\
            (self.initmoney, self.day, self.rate, self.ratemoney))
```

And input and print code are these.

```
a=ratecalc(10000, 7, 0.001)
print(a.__str__())
```

Comment: The attribute ratemoney is not there yet before you called your calc method.

Comment: This is why you have to initialize all the instance attributes in `__init__` method.

Comment: Your `ratecalc.__str__` method calls `self.ratemoney` which isn't an attribute of your instance until your `ratecalc.calc` method is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.ratemoney` is set by `self.calc()` so it does not exist before you actually call `.calc()` on your instance. Since you call `a.__str__()` before, and `__str__` depends on `self.ratemoney`, you indeed have an AttributeError.

A simple solution would be to call `self.calc()` in the `__init__` so `self.ratemoney` is always defined, but this value depends on the three other attributes so if you change any of those you will have a stale value in `ratemoney`.

A second (better) solution is to NOT store the value at all and use `self.calc()` in `__str__`:

def **str**(self):
        return('%.2f $ in %i days, rate was %i ,total is %s'%\
            (self.initmoney, self.day, self.rate, self.calc()))

If the computation cost is a problem (but it shouldn't be here) there are solutions to keep a local cache of the computed value and invalidate it when another attribute changes, but I don't think you need to worry about those kind of things now.

As a side note: Python's coding style recommands CamelCase for class names, so your class should be named `Ratecalc` or `RateCalc`. Also, special methods (methods with two leading and two final underscores) are not meant to be called directly, but via either an operator or a generic "operator-like" function. In your case, you should use

```
print(str(a))
```

instead of

```
print(a.__str__())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And also thanks to the useful side note!

Answer (score 0):

You have to put *ratemoney* into the initialiser before using it.

```
class ratecalc(object):
    def __init__(self, initmoney, day, rate):
        self.initmoney=initmoney
        self.day=day
        self.rate=rate
        self.ratemoney = None  #You have to initialise this before you use it
    def calc(self):
        self.ratemoney=self.initmoney+self.initmoney*rate*day
        return self.ratemoney
    def __str__(self):
        return('%.2f $ in %i days, rate was %i ,total is %s'%\
            (self.initmoney, self.day, self.rate, self.ratemoney))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

As you are not creating the attribute `ratemoney` in the `__init__` method, when you call the `__str__` method the attribute hasn't been created yet and therefore the error. The solution is to instantiate the attribute in the init even with a `None` value, but in this case when `day==0`, `ratemoney == initmoney` so that should be the value of your instantiation:

```
class ratecalc(object):
def __init__(self, initmoney, day, rate):
    self.initmoney=initmoney
    self.day=day
    self.rate=rate

    self.ratemoney=initmoney

def calc(self):
    self.ratemoney=self.initmoney+self.initmoney*rate*day
    return self.ratemoney
def __str__(self):
    return('%.2f $ in %i days, rate was %i ,total is %s'%\
        (self.initmoney, self.day, self.rate, self.ratemoney))
```

Answer (score 0):

you have used self.ratemoney before define the var, that is because you make the instance of the class and after, you use the method **str** wich return self.ratemoney but this attribute is not define until you use the method calc. 
You could define self.ratemoney in the **init** method or use the calc method before use **str**.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer:)